# uib-popover not working as expected with a DIV element

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm testing [uib-popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and everything seems to work fine in the plunkr but when I change button to div then the popup seems displaced.

Any idea why?

This is the code, simplified from the official plunkr

```
<div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Popover placement</label>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="placement.selected" ng-options="o as o for o in placement.options"></select>
    </div>
    <div popover-placement="{{placement.selected}}" uib-popover="On the {{placement.selected}}">Popover {{placement.selected}}</div>
</div>
```

And [here is the plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sn2C4ThJkyyAzvXNbNRz?p=preview) to test it.

Thanks!

Comment: In your code everything is DIV. Where is <button>

Comment: that's what I meant; if I change from <button> to <div>, the popover is displaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**div** is a *block* element while **button** is an *inline-block* element. Add style: inline-block to div, it work as expected.

```
<div style="display: inline-block;" popover-placement="{{placement.selected}}" uib-popover="On the {{placement.selected}}">Popover {{placement.selected}}</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/0UDLTv3ATEtXEjYnJQHF?p=preview

Comment: Here, you are assigned the selected as top. For my case if I reach right edge it should be left side, if it is left edge, it should show on right side. By auto it should work. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your popover  as follows:-
Just add `class="btn btn-default"` in your code and your pop-over will not displace. *Note:- there is still minor css fix required.*

```
<div popover-placement="{{placement.selected}}" uib-popover="On the {{placement.selected}}" class="btn btn-default">Popover {{placement.selected}}</div>
```